# How do i adress a dynamic generated textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables, session-state

I am creating a webshop and I am currently working on the shopping cart.I keep the products that the buyer wants in the shopping cart in sessions,and a table is generated on the "ShoppingCart" page.or each product in the shopping cart a row is created with a delete button, a text box for the number, and so on.I made a button "update cart" and when I press it I want the variable "number" of each product to be replaced there the number in the row of that product.but I don't know how to address the textboxes because, for example, "textbox1.text" doesn't work.

I do not know how many text boxes are going to be in advance .. that depends on how many different products the customer add's to his shopping cart.

some help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

This is the code where i generate the textboxes

```
private void vulCart()
        {
            myTable.Rows.Clear();

            //header row aan maken 
            TableRow rowH = new TableRow();
            TableCell cellH1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cellH2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cellH3 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cellH4 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cellH5 = new TableCell();
            TableCell cellH6 = new TableCell();

            cellH1.Text = "Id";
            cellH1.CssClass = "bold";

            cellH2.Text = "Product";
            cellH2.CssClass = "bold";

            cellH3.Text = "Prijs";
            cellH3.CssClass = "bold";

            cellH4.Text = "Aantal";
            cellH4.CssClass = "bold";

            cellH5.Text = "Totaal";
            cellH5.CssClass = "bold";

            cellH6.Text = "";
            cellH6.CssClass = "bold";

            rowH.Cells.Add(cellH1);
            rowH.Cells.Add(cellH2);
            rowH.Cells.Add(cellH3);
            rowH.Cells.Add(cellH4);
            rowH.Cells.Add(cellH5);
            rowH.Cells.Add(cellH6);

            myTable.Rows.Add(rowH);

            //generate a row for each items in session "shoppingcart"
            if (Session["ShoppingCart"] != null)
            {
                ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)Session["ShoppingCart"];

                double totaal = 0;

                // for elk product dat in shopping staat 
                for (int i = 0; i < cart.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    double totaalProduct = 0;

                    totaalProduct = Convert.ToDouble(cart.Items[i].Aantal) * Convert.ToDouble(cart.Items[i].Prijs);

                    TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();

                    Button btn_Delete = new Button();
                    btn_Delete.CssClass = "btn";
                    btn_Delete.Text = "Verwijder";
                    btn_Delete.Attributes.Add("ProductNaam", cart.Items[i].Product.ToString());
                    btn_Delete.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);

                    cell1.Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
                    cell2.Text = cart.Items[i].Product.ToString();
                    cell3.Text = cart.Items[i].Prijs.ToString();
                    cell4.Text = cart.Items[i].Aantal.ToString();
                    cell5.Text = totaalProduct.ToString();
                    cell6.Controls.Add(btn_Delete);




                    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell3);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell4);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell5);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell6);

                    myTable.Rows.Add(row);

                    totaal = totaal + totaalProduct;


                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Use FindControl `myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox`. Make sure to give the dynamic controls an `ID`.

Comment: Is the "TextBox1" the id ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to assign it yourself when using dynamic controls.